# Admin only - Anonymous Authentication - Firebase - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add anonymous authentication to my app using Firebase. But this error keeps repeating:

[image]

This is my code:

```
firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously()
    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user);
        } else {
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
            Toast.makeText(AnonymousLoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updateUI(null);
        }
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Identity by any chance? If so, this may mean that sign **up** is disallowed, and only sign-in is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not what I was looking for.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), here you can find a useful [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login anonymously using Firebase you have to enable the anonymous authentication option from the Firebase console.

[image: Solution to Anonymous Authentication - Firebase - Android]

To enable anonymous authentication, follow these steps:

1. Go to Firebse Console & login to your account.
2. Head over to the Authentication tab as shown above.
3. Click on **Add new provider** button, you'll see a pop up:

[image: Solution to Anonymous Authentication - Firebase - Android]

4. Click on **Anonymous** option, again you'll see a pop up:

[image: Solution to Anonymous Authentication - Firebase - Android]

5. Now click on **toggle** button to enable authentication
6. Click on **Save** button

After saving, you'll see the **Anonymous authentication** will be in **authencation list** as shown in the image below.

[image: Solution to Anonymous Authentication - Firebase - Android]

**This procedure works for me.**